# Algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Deduce that if $Z$ is an algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^2$ and $c\in\mathbb{C}$ then $$Y = \{ a\in\mathbb{C} : (a,c) \in Z \}$$ is either finite or all of $\mathbb{A}^1$. Deduce that $$\{ ( z,w) \in \mathbb{A}^2 : |z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1 \}$$ is not an algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Comment: Your question is part (b) of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295445/proving-algebraic-sets).